# concrete5 display ecommerce product attribute

Tags: php, content-management-system, e-commerce, concrete5

I want to display a custom attribute of eCommerce add-on. I know how to show product name, quantity, price but cant figure out how the attributes works. I want to display a specific attribute of the product.

Is this possible in showing the attributes? If so can anyone give my the syntax?

```
<?php   if ($displayNameP) { ?>
  <p><?php echo$link_before.$product->getProductName().$link_after?></p>
<?php   } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's anything like the core concrete5 objects (pages, users, files), then you'd do:

```
$product->getAttribute('attribute_handle')
```

Comment: You are right, it is the same. There is just the distinction between the actual Product and the Product in the Cart - for the product itself, $product->getAttribute($ak) or $product->getAttribute('attribute_value') works.